# Regex find content in between single quotes, but only if contains certain word

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, single-quotes

I want to get the content between single quotes, but only if it contains a certain word (i.e 'sample_2').  It additionally should not match ones with white space.

Input example: (The following should match and return only: `../sample_2/file` and `sample_2/file`)

```
['asdf', '../sample_2/file', 'sample_2/file', 'example with space', sample_2, sample]
```

Right now I just have that matched the first 3 items in the list:

```
'(.\S*?)'
```

I can't seem to find the right regex that would return those containing the word 'sample_2'

Comment: Is this a string? Why not use `ast.literal_eval` and turn it into a real list? Hard to tell what data type is here or whether it's part of JSON or something, but generally regex is not the right tool for the job for parsing serialized data structures.

Comment: @ggorlen is right for most cases. If you change it into a python list, then you can run filter on the items with a simpler regex.  Cases such as a file parser on untrusted dynamic output, would not be recommended to read back into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specific words/characters you need to have them in the regular expression and not use the '\S'.  The \S is the equivalent to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]` or "any non-whitespace character".

```py
import re

teststr = "['asdf', '../sample_2/file', 'sample_2/file', 'sample_2 with spaces','example with space', sample_2, sample]"
matches = re.findall(r"'([^\s']*sample_2[^\s]*?)',", teststr)
# ['../sample_2/file', 'sample_2/file']
```

Based on your wording, you suggest the desired word can change.  In that case, I would recommend using re.compile() to dynamically create a string which then defines the regular expression.

```py
import re
word = 'sample_2'
teststr = "['asdf', '../sample_2/file', 'sample_2/file', ' sample_2 with spaces','example with space', sample_2, sample]"

regex = re.compile("'([^'\\s]*"+word+"[^\\s]*?)',")
matches = regex.findall(teststr)
# ['../sample_2/file', 'sample_2/file']
```

Also if you haven't heard of this tool yet, check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).  I always build my regular expressions here to make sure I get them correct.  It gives you the references, explanation of what is happening and even lets you test it right there in the browser.

### Explanation of regex

```py
regex = r"'([^\s']*sample_2[^\s]*?)',"
```

*Find first apostrophe, start group capture. Capture anything except a whitespace character or the corresponding ending apostrophe.  It must see the letters "sample_2" before accepting any non-whitespace character.  Stop group capture when you see the closing apostrophe and a comma.*

**Note:** In python, a string " or ' prepositioned with the character 'r' means the text is compiled as a regular expression.  Strings with the character 'r' also do not require double-escape '\' characters.